# Winston - append log data into JSON array

Tags: node.js, json, formatting, winston

I'm using Winston for logging like this:

```
const logger = createLogger({
format: format.json(),
transports: [
    new transports.File({
        level: 'error',
        format: format.combine(filterOnly('error'),
            format.timestamp({
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
            }),
            format.json()),
        filename: './audit_log/error.json',
    })]
});
```

I would like my log dato to end up in a JSON file with a structure like this:

```
{
"log": [
    {
        "message": "",
        "level": "",
        "timestamp": ""
    },
    {
        "message": "",
        "level": "",
        "timestamp": ""
    }
```

Instead of:

```
{"message":"Bundle uploaded file","level":"error","timestamp":"2019-02- 
28T07:48:59.821Z"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logger writes entries to the file as it goes, how would it close the file for every statement? You can easily format a standard file into a proper json object if you want at any point:

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('logfile')
})

const log = []
readline.on('line', line => log.push(JSON.parse(line)))
```

You can easily do something similar using bash